# window.onload not firing for function named onload

Tags: javascript, window, onload

Today I ran into a strange problem:

`window.onload` does not seem to fire when referencing a function called `onload`.

I have never noticed this before:

**Test 1** :

```js
window.onload=onload;
function onload(){
  console.log('event fired');
}
```

**Test 2** :

```js
window.onload=onload2;
function onload2(){
  console.log('event fired');
}
```

Why doesn't the first code work?

Answer (score 0):

Onload is pre-defind/prebuilt javascript function you cannot overwrite.that y it not work.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because of the scope. If you leave out `window.` in your second example, [the alert will still fire](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xeXQPy). In the first example, you are overwriting the `window.onload` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it that way you will be overwriting the onload predefined function built from javascript. But if you want to give the name onload to your function you can do it this way.

```js
function onload() {
  alert("Page is loaded");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="onload()">

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: document.body.onload=onload is also a programmatic way

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that in web browsers, the `window` is set as the global object. This means that `window.onload` and `onload` are referring to the same property.

```js
console.log(window.onload === onload); // true
```

So what you are essentially doing is

```
window.onload = window.onload;
```

which doesn't change anything.

If you want a function with the same name, you can put it in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (or in any function for that matter). In that case the function you define will not be put in the global scope and therefore it wont conflict with the existing `window.onload`.

```js
(function() {
  window.onload = onload;

  function onload() {
    console.log('event fired');
  }
})();
```

If you don't necessarily value the function name you can, next to changing the function name, also assign the function directly to the `onload` like so:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log('event fired');
};
```